# Counterexample of closed graph theorem when the image space is Hausdorff space but not compact?

Tags: general-topology, closed-graph

Closed graph theorem on topological space requires the image space Y is compact Hausdorff. Some counter examples on Wikipedia are all non-Hausdorff which is considered more exotic examples.

What are the examples in which the map X->Y is continuous but not closed (as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem, not the closed map in general topology), and the image space Y is Hausdorff but not compact?

Comment: In topology a closed map is one which maps closed sets to closed sets. There is a different definition in Functional Analysis. You to say what you mean by a closed map.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'v made it clear now.

Comment: As the article you linked says, any continuous map to a Hausdorff space has closed graph.  Compactness is relevant only to the reverse implication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such example. Aa long as $Y$ is Hausdorff the graph of $f$ is closed
: Let $(x_i,f(x_i))_{i \in I}$ be  a net in the graph converging to $(x,y)$ in the product topology. Then $x_i \to x$ and $f(x_i) \to y$. By continuity $f(x_i) \to f(x)$. Since limits are unique in a Hausdorff space  we get $y=f(x)$. Hence the graph is closed.

Comment: Why are you talking about C? The graph of the map is the sheet defined by f(x,y)=x which is closed in R3 right?

Comment: I deleted the question then I saw your answer...